# Downsampling, or equalizing vector lengths in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, sampling, resampling

I'm having somewhat of a basic problem yet I can't seem to solve it. I have two very large pieces of data. I have a matrix A that is 48554 x 1 and and a matrix B that is 160272 x 1. What I want to do is "downsample" matrix B so that it is of the same length as matrix A. Moreover, I want a function that can do this for pretty much any large m x 1 and n x 1 matrices (so that it works for more than this specific example). I tried using the resample function like so:

```
resample(B,length(A),length(B))
```

However I'm getting an error indicating that the filter length is too large. Next I tried using a for loop to simply extract every ith element from matrix B and save it into a new matrix, but this was not working out so nicely since the vector lengths aren't divisible by an integer. Does anyone have other (hopefully simple) ways to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the interp1 function. I know that down-sampling isn't really interpolating per se. Here's an example:

```
x1 = [0:0.1:pi];%vector length is 32
x2 = [0:0.01:pi];% vector length is 315

y1 = sin(x1);
y2 = sin(x2);

%down sample y2 to be same length as y1
y3 = interp1(x2,y2,x1);%y3 length is 32

figure(1)
plot(x2,y2);
hold on
plot(x1,y1,'k^');
plot(x1,y3,'rs');

% in general use this method to down-sample (or up-sample) any vector:
% resampled = interp1(current_grid,current_vector,desired_grid);
% where the desired_grid is a monotonically increasing vector of the desired length
% For example:

x5 = [0.0:0.001:1-0.001];
y5 = sin(x);
% If I want to down sample y5 to be 100 data points instead of 1000:
y6 = interp1([1:length(y5)],y5,1:1:100);

% y6 is now 100 data point long. Notice I didn't use any other data except for y6, the length of y6 and my desired length.
```

Comment: OK, does that mean I was correct in saying that this problem can't be solved with the resample function?

Comment: OK, I just tried what you said and I got this error:
"The grid vectors are not strictly monotonic increasing."

Does this method assume that the two vectors are similar functions? They're not in my case. I apologize if I should have pointed that out.

Comment: Ok sorry, I've edited my answer to include a better explanation. It doesn't matter that the two vectors are different functions. The error you saw is likely because you gave it the wrong inputs for the "x" or grid variables. Please see my answer again for an additional example.